# statement in php not executing into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

so im trying to prepare a simple INSERT stmt into my sql, the thing is that by the end of the code, which does not give anytime of errors, the new row is not created on database.
Thx in advance.

```
if ($insert_stmt = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO socios (id, stam ,primeiro_nome, ultimo_nome, email, 
                                cod_postal, localidade, password, salt) 
                                VALUES (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
            $stam = 1555;
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('isssisss', $stam ,$primeiro_nome, $ultimo_nome, 
                                $email, $cod_postal, $localidade, 
                                $password, $random_salt);
            // Execute the prepared query.
            mysqli_stmt_execute($insert_stmt);
            $affected_rows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
            if (! $affected_rows == 1) {
                header('Location: error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
            }
            header('Location: register_success.php');
        }
        else {
            header('Location: error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT2');
        }
```

Comment: check for errors then. I see no error checking here.

Comment: So - where do you get redirected to after query?

Comment: i got redirected to the register_success.php. And i don't get any erros when executing this code.

Comment: You sure asked a lot of questions but accepted none.

Comment: What? don't know what are you talking about?

Comment: You have asked a lot of question and have yet to accept any answers. This site goes both ways. If you expect help you should reward those who help you by accepting their answer. Read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and start giving back to the community.

Comment: ohhh you're right sory i will reward people then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute my code.

```
<?
$query = "INSERT INTO socios(stam ,primeiro_nome, ultimo_nome, email, 
                                cod_postal, localidade, password, salt) 
                                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query)) 
{
    $stam = 1555;
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "isssisss", $stam ,$primeiro_nome, $ultimo_nome, 
                        $email, $cod_postal, $localidade, 
                        $password, $random_salt);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $affected_rows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
    if ($affected_rows != 1) 
    {
        header('Location: error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
    }

    header('Location: register_success.php');

}
else
{
    header('Location: error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT2');
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you very much it works!!

Comment: Glad to help Mr @RicardoSacramento

Comment: Ok so i finally found my error your code worked but only one time, i had an error on my syntax where i don't know, but after that it started not working again so i finally found out that my camp stam is an unique camp so i was trying to insert the same stay over and over again without success. Ver thanks!!

Comment: Glad to hear that you found your error @RicardoSacramento.
~~ "Everone do mistake. But, not everyone find their mistake."

Answer (score 2):

The coding error seems to be in this line:

```
$affected_rows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
```

That should read:

```
$affected_rows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($insert_stmt);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php

Comment: thx i tried modify the code but still the same result i go to the registration success and not input on the database

Comment: Can you verify if all your parameters contain values? Because the posted code (with the tiny correction on `stmt`) is ok. Especially `cod_postal` is something to watch: You state it is an integer, is it really an integer when testing?

Comment: the cod_postal is in the database MEDIUMINT i don't know if the 'i'  is correct then, but i checked the value passing is indeed an int

Comment: Oh, 1 more change: If you have an ID column (auto_increment), you do not have to use the `NULL` insert: Just remove the `id` column from you insert and it will work ok.

Comment: still not doing nothing =(

Comment: Ok, check if you are entering your `if($insert_stmt` (You did not post the code from before this statement, and since everything looks ok in the statement, the code might have a typo before the posted statement)